# How is it possible to recover properties of compactness, connectedness, hausdorff, of topological space by using the category of sheaves

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, topos-theory

I will rephrase the title :

How is it possible to effectively recover/express all classical properties stated above of a topological space by using the category of presheaves of open subsets ?

Comment: At best you can hope to recover the lattice of open subsets, which I think you can do. This recovers the original space if the space is sober but not in general.

Comment: A presheaf is a contravariant functor from $O(X)$ to what category? Or what else do you mean by the category of presheaves?

Comment: the set of all open subsets of a topological space is a poset, hence form a category, a functor from this category to the category of sets is a presheaf but it could be any category as the target.
I just wanted to know how to express these classical properties of a topological space but now expressed in categorial formalism

Comment: by category of presheaves I mean a category where the objects are functors from the category formed by all open subsets to another category

Comment: If you were referring to the category of sheaves instead of the category of presheaves, it would work as follows: The set of subobjects of the terminal object of the category of sheaves is canonically a poset, and in fact it is isomorphic to the poset of opens of your given space. Hence you can recover the poset of opens. This is enough to, for instance, detect compactness and locality. In general, you'll need the sobrity condition Qiaochu already mentioned.